# How to analyze the data having range (e.g. 5 to 7 hours, 7 to 9 hours)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normalization

Let's say, I am asking the students "Per day, how long do you study?" There are 10 students and they replied like the following:

[image: Table]

Now, I want to find the students who study much. Let's say, I am considering, 8 hours as the threshold value for the consideration of study much.

**So, What confuses me?**

There are five students (Serial no. 1, 3, 5, 8, 10) whose study time varies up to 8 hours. Should I consider them as the students who study much?

Basically, I am seeking for a statistically valid way to convert duration of each students to a fixed value (e.g. 6.75 hours instead of 5.5 to 8 hours) so that I can do it without any ambiguity.

Comment: There won't be statistically valid way to do this, since there's no statistical parameters around the students' answers. Someone might have answered with the absolute limits of how long they've ever studied in a day, someone else might have answered what's typical perhaps 75% of the time, and someone else might have answered something that's typical at the low end and unusual at the high end. You could take just the center of the range as a reasonable guess at "average time spend studying", but there's no guarantee that actually reflects reality.

Comment: I generally agree with the foregoing comment that conversion to a fixed value is not valid, as students specified an *approximate* range of study hours. And, what’s more complicated, is each *range* isn’t fixed. This often happens when you do not specify a plausible interval of ‘study time’ to choose from. Have you also considered binning hours into low, medium, and high study durations? This may be difficult with few students, but it is something else to consider.

Comment: Normally you cannot avoid ambiguity, but for these sample data you can: by setting any threshold in the open interval $(8,10)$ you will clearly separate students 1,3,4,5,8, and 10 from the rest.  There's little more one can say without knowing what kind of statistical analysis you intend to do with these data.  Perhaps their best use is to suggest ways to improve the question in future administrations of this survey instrument so that you can obtain consistent, commensurate answers.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your valuable feedback.